# Getting error in ScriptResource.asxd after migrating website from target framework 3.5 to 4.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptresource.axd

My website was in initially at target framework 3.5, and i have changed it to 4.5,
everything works fine , when i click button on a page where script manager is added it shows following exception:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager[image]ServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 500

whenever i click this compiler button in my page it shows the above pasted(screenshot) error, this error comes in ScriptResource.axd

Comment: Do you have any changes in web config after migration? Do you use Ajax Control Toolkit library? This type of information can help to identify the problem.

Comment: Did you update the axd handlers in your web.config to 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

try adding below line in your httphandlers and handlers section in web.config file.

```
<add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>
```

Please comment here and let others know if and when issue is resolved.